# gradle log - redirect 'info' to file and 'quiet' to console

Tags: jenkins, gradle, logging, log4j

my issue is as follows

Jenkins logs have become impossible to load (we are running gradle with info flag).
So, naturally we thought about splitting gradle log - quiet to console, and info and above to file. when jenkins finishes we want to upload the file to the jenkins job.

i've tried manipulating gradle logger, adding log4j.properties but nothing seems to effect gradle logging.

searched online and found
some old answers, suggesting this is virtually impossible:

[Lifecycle to Console and Info to File?](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/lifecycle-to-console-and-info-to-file/25286)

[Logging to console and file](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/logging-to-console-and-file/8635)

is it still the case?
or in the new versions of gradle there is a way to do this?

thanks so much

Comment: You can add a custom logger and do whatever in it - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:changing_what_gradle_logs. Alternatively, determine what the noise in the logs is and determine whether it’s actually _useful_. Likely it is simply noise - turn down the logging.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you so much for the quick and insightful response. these solutions will not work for us: 1. custom loggers are used for different gradle stages (task, evaluation, etc.) but i want to redirect the entire gradle log for a range of log levels. 2. we want to turn down the noise, but if an error occurs we want to have an option to access a log file with deeper information and understand the cause.

Comment: There is a feature request you can vote on here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1005 (not that it helps you right now of cause :) )